# In assembly... can't get delegatecall to work

Tags: assembly, delegatecall

Delegatecall can be used in either solidity or assembly.

In solidity, I can get it working with the following code:

```
bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature ("get_value(uint16,uint16)", var1, var2);
bool success;
bytes memory result;
(success, result) = my_contract.delegatecall (payload);
```

The above code calls `my_contract.get_value(var1, var2)`.

How can I do the same thing in assembly? The function is defined like this:

```
delegatecall (gas, address, in, insize, out, outsize)
```

If I am in an assembly block, assuming `address` is supposed to be the address of the contract that contains the function being called, how would it ever know which function I intend to call? When I do it using solidity, it knows this from the encoded payload data that I pass into it. But the assembly function only takes an address. And it always returns 0.

I have not been able to find any good documentation for EVM assembly anywhere on the Internet.

EDIT: Below is one of the attempts I made, using an example from the Internet.

```
let freememstart := mload (0x40)
calldatacopy (freememstart, 0, calldatasize ())
success := delegatecall (not (0), my_contract, freememstart, calldatasize (), freememstart, 32)
```

EDIT 2: Another attempt I made, not using calldatacopy.

```
bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature ("get_value(uint16,uint16)", var1, var2);
uint payload_size = payload.length * 8;

assembly
{
    let freememstart := mload (0x40)

    mstore (0x40, add (freememstart, payload_size))
    mstore (freememstart, payload)

    let output := mload (0x40)
    mstore (0x40, add (output, 0x20))

    success := delegatecall (not (0), contract_addr, freememstart, payload_size, output, 0x20)
}
```

Comment: What code did you write? What error did you get?

Comment: I edited the post to show one of the attempts I made to call it in assembly. I can't see how it could possibly work though, because it has no way of knowing which function I intend to call. I don't get an error message; it returns 0. But I don't get the expected result either. The same thing happens when I try to use call or staticcall in assembly. There is no place to pass it the function hash.

Comment: Does the delegatecall work if used from solidity, ie without using assembly? Remember that if the method do not exists the fallback function will be executed instead, so a bad call might appear to work.

Comment: Yes, when I call it in solidity, it works.

Comment: The code passes message's calldata to delegatecall as input. Don't you want to pass the payload instead?

Comment: That was only one of my attempts. I have also tried passing the payload, but I never got that to work either. I placed the entire payload in the "in" location and set insize to the size of the payload in bytes. Then I added enough space for a return value in the out and outsize parameters. But it has always returned 0 and I've never been able to get any valid return data from it either. Works just find in solidity though.

Comment: I added another edit which shows another attempt I made to call it. In the new example I added, I am multiplying the payload size by 8 because it didn't work with the size measured in bytes. But it doesn't work this way either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things you should be aware of:

- Don't need to copy memory to the free pointer, you can use any memory pointer. The EVM will copy the memory to the target so it will not be modified.
- The first 32 bytes from payload is the array's length. When passing that memory probably want to skip those bytes. That is the reason behind `add(payload, 32)`.

Something like this should work in your case

```
bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature ("get_value(uint16,uint16)", var1, var2);
uint ret;
bool success;

assembly
{
    let output := mload (0x40)
    success := delegatecall(gas(),
        contract_addr,
        add(payload, 32),
        mload(payload),
        output,
        0x20)
    ret := mload(output)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look the existing proxy contracts like OpenZeppelin's `Proxy` as an example:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-labs/blob/master/upgradeability_using_eternal_storage/contracts/Proxy.sol